# php openssl_public_encrypt(): key parameter is not a valid public key

Tags: php, encryption, openssl, rsa

```
function encrypt($string) {

    $key = "MFwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADSwAwSAJBAIiJg//yXqt7ln+orfSuRjH0FjTKQyj6ti2tX8PR8yhvoeocfHg0RtBNBJFaghoezGgbsmsUcac8GSgoiL9kzzMCAwEAAQ==";

    $keyFinal = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\r\n" . chunk_split($key) . "\r\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";

    openssl_public_encrypt($string, $encrypted_data, $keyFinal);

    echo base64_encode($encrypted_data); 
}
```

(Every other key I try gives the same error, too)

am trying to encrypt a string using rsa but i get an error (openssl_public_encrypt(): key parameter is not a valid public key)

i have been trying to do this for hours now please help

Comment: So how did you generate that public key? Did you just make it up?

Comment: I get my public key from an api using a get request i developed a web app with angular using the same key and it worked i cant get it working in php this key isnt my real public key i generated this one using an online generator but it didnt work with my real key too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `chunk_split` includes a trailing separator, which in your case is `\r\n`. So in your case, just don't concatenate an extra one in.

Change this:

```php
$keyFinal = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\r\n" . chunk_split($key) . "\r\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
```

To this:

```php
$keyFinal = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\r\n" . chunk_split($key) . "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
```

Comment: It worked thank you, i cant believe it was this simple.